# Gremlin API: how to traverse vertices, collect properties conditionally, and stop when collected properties reach a certain limit

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm new to graphs and Gremlin API although I find it promising for my purpose so I am investigating and despite looking at documentation and several tutorials, I can't seem to find how to do this.

A portion of my graph would have vertices representing "documents" with "id" (1, 2, 3, ...) and "author" (a: Luc, Kim, ...) properties. They are linked with simple "next" edges. Like this:

```
V1{a:'Luc'} -> V2{a:'Kim'} -> V3{a:'Marc'} -> V4{a:'Kim'} -> V5{a:'Luc'} -> V6{a:'Luc'}
```

What I am trying to do:

- start at any known location from the vertice id (eg.: V(2))
- go either "up" with in() or "down" with out() (eg.: out())
- somehow "collect" the ids of vertices that have their author part of an array (eg.: ['Luc', 'Kim'])
- keep going until I have collected at most a certain number of ids (which will, in most cases be smaller than the number of vertices I will traverse to collect them), or until I reach the end (eg.: maximum 3)

So for this example, I would expect the result to be: [2, 4, 5].

From what I found so far, I would have something like:

```
g.V(2).repeat(somethingThatKeepsTheIdIfAuthorIsInArray(['Luc', 'Kim']).out()).until("I have found 3 ids")
```

Or if I word it differently, I want to "skip" vertex 3 because its author is not in the list, but keep going until I find at most 3 vertices that match my condition or I reach then end.

Any idea of what step(s) I should be looking at to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

I kept digging and found this to be a possible solution :

```
g.v('D2').emit(has('author', within('Luc', 'Kim'))).repeat(out()).limit(3).values('id').fold()
```

Which yields:

```
['D2', 'D4', 'D5']
```

I also confirmed that it works correctly no matter from which vertex we start. For example starting a D5 yields:

```
['D5', 'D6']
```

The only concern (question) I have about this is how the limit(3) is applied ? Does it actually break the repeat loop when 3 vertices are emitted or will the repeat loop traverse all vertices until there are no more "next" edge, THEN truncate the result to only return 3 ?

Comment: Note that the `g.v` should be `g.V` in your example. If you are using real IDs (as in the sample graph in my answer), your query will need to use `id()` rather than `values('id')` The `limit` should not be a problem.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence Strange because I was testing with g.v as well as values('id') and both were working. Could it be because I am using the Microsoft Azure Cosmos DB implementation under the hood ? Also would you happen to know a piece of doc that states that limit() can indeed be used to break a repeat() loop ? I'm yet to find one...

Comment: That's very possible. In purely Gremlin terms `g.v` is not valid and would fail if you used my sample graph with TinkerGraph. The same for `values('id')` that should only return a property with the key of `id` not an actual ID. The `limit` step works because the `emit` is present. It is not "breaking" the `repeat` per-se.

Answer (score 0):

Using this graph

```java
g.addV('Document').property('author','Luc').property(id,'D1').as('d1').
  addV('Document').property('author','Kim').property(id,'D2').as('d2').
  addV('Document').property('author','Marc').property(id,'D3').as('d3').
  addV('Document').property('author','Kim').property(id,'D4').as('d4').
  addV('Document').property('author','Luc').property(id,'D5').as('d5').
  addV('Document').property('author','Luc').property(id,'D6').as('d6').
  addE('NEXT').from('d1').to('d2').
  addE('NEXT').from('d2').to('d3').
  addE('NEXT').from('d3').to('d4').
  addE('NEXT').from('d4').to('d5').
  addE('NEXT').from('d5').to('d6')
```

We can write a Gremlin query that tests for certain author's names and uses a `sideEffect` to store the ones that match.

```java
g.V('D2').
  repeat(out('NEXT').sideEffect(has('author',within('Luc','Kim')).id().store('documents'))).
  until(not(out('NEXT'))).
  select('documents')
```

Which will return

```
['D4', 'D5', 'D6']
```

With a small change to the query, we can also test for a maximum number of documents.

```java
g.V('D2').
  repeat(out('NEXT').
         sideEffect(has('author',within('Luc','Kim')).id().store('documents'))).
  until(not(out('NEXT')).or().select('documents').count(local).is(2)).
  select('documents')
```

Which yields

```
['D4', 'D5']
```

To include the starting vertex in the results, we can just put the `sideEffect` first in the `repeat` step.

```java
g.V('D2').
  repeat(out('NEXT').
         sideEffect(has('author',within('Luc','Kim')).id().store('documents'))).
  until(not(out('NEXT')).or().select('documents').count(local).is(2)).
  select('documents')
```

Which yields

```
['D2', 'D4', 'D5']
```

**UPDATED 2021-11-17**

In response to the comments/discussion below, here are two more examples of the query in use/ The fist starts at D2 with an `is(3)` and the second starts at D4. These were run using the Gremlin Console and TinkerGraph. While my query works, now that I fully understand your requirements, I think it is a bit over-engineered for your case. The answer you have since posted I think is fine for this case. The one caveat being, as we discussed in comments, that your query as written will fail on most TinkerPop enabled stores but seems to be working the way you need on CosmosDB. I up-voted your answer  :-)

```java
gremlin> g.V('D2').
......1>   repeat(out('NEXT').
......2>          sideEffect(has('author',within('Luc','Kim')).id().store('documents'))).
......3>   until(__.not(out('NEXT')).or().select('documents').count(local).is(3)).
......4>   select('documents')   

==>[D4,D5,D6]   



gremlin> g.V('D4').
......1>   repeat(out('NEXT').
......2>          sideEffect(has('author',within('Luc','Kim')).id().store('documents'))).
......3>   until(__.not(out('NEXT')).or().select('documents').count(local).is(3)).
......4>   select('documents')     

==>[D5,D6]
```

Comment: In the last example, I guess sideEffect has to come first, correct ? And is must be is(3), right ? Also I am wondering if this example works if you start at D4 ? Will the last vertex (D6) be returned ?

Comment: The value of `is` can be whatever you need. I just hard coded a 3 for this example. Your other example is fine as well. I probably over engineered my answer thinking you had a few other things you wanted control over.

Comment: In your last example, the out('NEXT') comes first and the is() is harcoded to 2. I believe these are mistakes.

Comment: And also I am not able to reproduce your last example as is; for some reason, it seems Cosmos DB does nto like not(out('NEXT')). But I am wondering if you tested your solution when starting at 'D4' as I believe it will not work and 'D6' will not be returned.

Comment: D6 will be returned. I will update the answer.